# Construct traceless symmetric tensors

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors

I understand how to create a traceless symmetric tensor, like $$ \hat{X}_{ij} = X_{ij} - \frac{1}{N}\delta_{ij}X_{hh} $$ with Einstein convention of summing over repeated indices.

(By the way, I'm following here the book "Group Theory in a Nutshell for Physicists", by A. Zee).

But for a 3-tensor I understand that you contract by pairs of indices, but why this normalization factor?

$$ \hat{X}_{ijk} = X_{ijk} - \frac{1}{N + 2}(\delta_{ij}X_{hhk} + \delta_{ik}X_{hhj} + \delta_{jk}X_{hhi}) $$

What is the pattern here? How do you generalize to even higher order tensors? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, I think in the general case we can generalize the formula in the following way. If $\delta_{ii}=N$ and we got n indexes:
$\hat{X}_{i_1i_2...i_n}:=X_{i_1i_2...i_n}−\frac{n}{N+n-1} \delta_{(i_1 i_2}X_{i_3...i_n)hh}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming $X_{ijk}$ is symmetric, by symmetry of notation so is $\hat X_{ijk}$, and thus all traces give the same tensor. Then, the trace of $X$ is $X_{iik}$, and if we trace the quantity in parentheses over $_{ij}$, we get $\delta_{ii} X_{hhk} + \delta_{ik} X_{hhi} + \delta_{ik} X_{hhi}$, but $\delta_{ii} = N$, so the quantity in parentheses is $(N + 2) X_{hhk}$. Thus (after relabeling the dummy index $h$) we see that the coefficient must be $\frac{1}{N + 2}$ for $\hat X$ to be tracefree.

With this in hand, I think you can work out the formula for the tracefree part of a symmetric tensor of general rank for yourself.

**Remark** We can emphasize the symmetry of the formula by instead writing it as $$\hat X_{ijk} := X_{ijk} - \frac{3}{N + 2} \delta_{(ij} X_{k)hh} .$$ Here, the parentheses enclosing the indices ${}_i, {}_j, {}_k$ indicate that we symmetrize over them.

Comment: Does this imply that a traceless symmetric 3-tensor is identically zero.?

Comment: In general, no: If we denote the underlying vector space here by $\Bbb V$, the trace here is a (linear) map $$\operatorname{tr}:\mathsf{S}^3 \Bbb V \to \Bbb V ,$$ and if we denote the inner product on $\Bbb V $ by $g$, computing gives that $\operatorname{tr} \widehat{g \otimes X}$ is some nonzero multiple of $X$, so the map is surjective. So the space $\ker \operatorname{tr}$ of tracefree, symmetric $3$-forms has dimension $$\dim \ker \operatorname{tr} = \dim \mathsf{S}^3 \Bbb V - \dim \Bbb V = {{\dim \Bbb V+2} \choose 3} - \dim \Bbb V ,$$ which is positive when $\dim \Bbb V > 1$.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe I was not clear enough. Assume I have the tensor $L_{ijk}$ that is symmetric in all indices and $g^{ij}L_{ijk}=g^{ij}L_{ikj}=g^{ij}L_{kij}=0$. Does this imply $L_{ijk}=0.$ If yes, I do appreciate recommending a reference to the proof.

Comment: I think that's the same question: Since your $L_{ijk}$ is symmetric, all three of the traces you write are the same; e.g., $L_{ijk} = L_{ikj}$, and contracting both sides with $g^{ij}$ gives the leftmost equality.

For a minimal example, suppose $\Bbb V$ has dimension $2$; we can choose a basis $(E_1, E_2)$ for which, in the dual basis $(e^1, e^2)$, we have $$g = (e^1)^2 + (e^2)^2.$$ Then, take $L$ to be full symmetrization of $$e^1 \otimes (e^1 \otimes e^1 - 3 e^2 \otimes e^2) .$$ In this dimension, $\dim \ker \operatorname{tr} = 2$, which agrees with the formula in my previous comment.