# Traceless tensor product: unclear definition

Tags: matrices, tensor-products, tensors, trace

I do not understand [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2105.12117.pdf) on the page $8$
that in the definition of `traceless tensor product` there are 3 indices $i,j,k$
in the rightmost term but in the preceding term and in front of the equality sign $=$
both have just two indices $i,j$.

Also, is there used the Einstein summation convention in this formula ?

Lastly, what is the fraction in front of the rightmost term intended to mean $-\frac{1}{2}\delta_{ij}\cdot$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2910198/construct-traceless-symmetric-tensors

Comment: @bangs Your link seems to solve something more general. I'm not an expert on tensors and the traceless version of the tensor is still unclear to me. The only thing I've understood is that $k$ is being to sum over so one loses the extra index, am I correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the dimension is $N$ (in the paper, $N=2$, but we work more generally).

$\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker delta. Its components are given by $\delta_{ij}=1$ if $i=j$ and $0$ if $i\neq j$.  So according to page $8$ of the linked paper, $f\hat{\otimes}g$ has $i,j$ component $ f_ig_j-\frac{1}{N}\delta_{ij}f_kg_k$, using the summation convention.  This is equal to $$(f\hat{\otimes}g)_{ij} = \left\{\begin{array}{cc} f_ig_i - \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^N f_kg_k & : i = j \\ f_ig_j & : i \neq j. \end{array}\right.$$ That's because the Kronecker delta is only non-zero when $i=j$.

To get the trace, we sum \begin{align*} \sum_{i=1}^N (f\hat{\otimes} g)_{ii} & = \sum_{i=1}^N\Bigl[f_ig_i - \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^N f_kg_k\Bigr] \\ & = \sum_{i=1}^N f_ig_i - \sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N f_kg_k \\ & = \sum_{i=1}^N f_ig_i - \sum_{i=1}^N f_ig_i=0.\end{align*}

Imagine subtracting $1/N$ of the trace down the diagonal, so that when you sum down the diagonal, each of the $\text{trace}/N$ pieces sums up to subtracting the trace once.

Comment: Great. What is your collocation `trace / N pieces`. Is `/` a division sign here ?

Comment: Yes. I've edited my answer to try to make it clearer.